# passing data in json format from webpage to flask app

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, python-3.x, flask

- I want to sent data in `json` format from a webpage to `flask` using `ajax` post method. My tries are as follows :

MY TRY: mytest.html(code snippet)

```
var jsondat = JSON.stringify(table.getData());
console.log(jsondat);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '127.0.0.1:5000/test',
    // contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    data: {
        'data': jsondat
    },
    success: function(response) {
        alert("HELLO")
    },
});
```

Flask App:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<string:page_name>/')
def render_static(page_name):
    return render_template('%s.html' % mytest)


@app.route('/test')
def testfun():
    content = request.get_json(silent=True)
    print(content)
    return 'The test'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: Does your try work? What happens when you try it?